# Switch button caption game

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to make a java GUI program "game".

There are five buttons, each with a character as the button caption. When a button is clicked, the caption of that button is exchanged with the right hand neighbor. If the far right button is clicked, then the far left button has that caption, so they both switch (it wraps around).

The goal is to have them arranged alphabetically, thus ending the game.

I can't think of an intuitive way to have the characters switching without having to make five  buttons.

```
String str = "abcde"; // DEBUG ARGUMENT STRING
setCaptions(str);
```

Method that takes the string, creates a char array out of them, and creates buttons...

```
void setCaptions(String string){
    char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<Character> arrList = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for (int x=0; x < charArray.length; x++) {
        String str = Character.toString(charArray[x]);
        btn = new JButton(str);
        btn.setFont(myFont);
        pane.add(btn, "LR");
        btn.addActionListener(new SwitchAction());
        arrList.add(str.charAt(0));
    }


    // check the order...
    System.out.print(arrList);
    if (arrList.get(0) < arrList.get(1) 
            && arrList.get(1) < arrList.get(2) 
            && arrList.get(2) < arrList.get(3) 
            && arrList.get(3) < arrList.get(4)) {
        lbl.setText("SOLVED");
    }
}
```

ActionListener to switch the captions, which I can't figure out...

```
public class SwitchAction implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String a = btn.getText();

        System.out.println(evt.getActionCommand() + " pressed"); // debug

        // something goes here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have an array or ArrayList of JButton, `ArrayList<JButton>` and put your buttons into this list.

Your ActionListener will need a reference to the original class so it can get a hold of the ArrayList. It can then iterate through the array list find out which button was pressed, which is its neighbor, and do its swap. So pass that reference in via a constructor parameter, and then in the actionPerformed method, call a `getList()` or similar "getter" method to get the ArrayList and iterate through it.

i.e.,

```
public class MyListener implements ActionListener {
  private OriginalGui gui;

  public MyListener(OriginalGui gui) {
    this.gui = gui;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton pressedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
    ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = gui.getButtonList();

    // ... iterate through list and find button.
  }
}
```